# "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts" in UWP app (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

I'm trying to connect a UWP app written in C# to a MySQL DB hosted on another machine on the local network (it's on a Raspberry Pi, but I doubt that makes a difference). The code I have right now is:

```cs
string M_str_sqlcon = "Server=192.168.0.101;Port=3306;Database=****;User ID=****;Password=****;";
MySqlConnection mysqlcon = new MySqlConnection(M_str_sqlcon);
MySqlCommand mysqlcom = new MySqlCommand("select * from mysql.users", mysqlcon);
mysqlcon.Open();
```

However, the code fails with a 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.' error. Here's the pic of the error pop-up.

[image: The error message.]

I've tried changing the server address, and if I enter one that isn't present on the local network, it fails with a different error (along the lines of Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts, cannot reach target server).

I've tried various connection strings I've found around StackOverflow, and in MS' own docs, but nothing seems to help.

I can properly ping the DB IP from the machine I'm developing this app on, and I can access the database normally using MySQL Workbench, so I'm sure it isn't a problem with the user permissions/settings.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Pasting the full exception call stack (from your application may help us identify the cause of the problem). http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/
Also, for UWP, it _may_ help to switch from MySql.Data to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ (they have the same API, but MySqlConnector has better cross-platform support).

Comment: Do you have the private network capability?

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect with the database using some GUI tools. If it works you will be sure that there is a problem with your application. It could be network problems etc.

Comment: I've already stated in my answer that I've tried with MySQL Workbench, and it works just fine. I've forgot to add that a python script connecting to the database also works properly, so I'm sure its not down to the network.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't notice it. 
Try base version without the command.
Remove the third line and try again.

Comment: Nope, nothing changes if I delete the query.

Comment: Spacing may matter, try standard format:
"Server=myServerAddress; Port=1234; Database=myDataBase; Uid=myUsername; Pwd=myPassword;"

Comment: I've seen information that turning off the VPN could help.

Comment: Already did, I’ve tried all the spacing formats and nothing really helps. I’ve also got no VPN running at the moment.